# How do I connect multiple monitors to a Dell XPS 17 3D

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors

I have a 2011 Dell XPS 17 3D with a 2nd generation Intel Core i7-2720QM processor. It has a 17.3" FHD WLED AG (1920 x 1080) screen and I would like to add an additional Dell monitor and use both simultaneously. Is this possible and if so what cable do I use and how do I set it up? Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked to see what video connectors the XPS17 has built in? If it does not have any, then you likely need to purchase a port replicator to connector additional screens. The Dell XPS laptops should work with the Dell USB Dock just fine.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see you have Mini DisplayPort and HDMI on your laptop (please check that in specification/manual) so in order to connect another monitor you need **Mini DisplayPort** or **HDMI** to **HDMI**/**DVI**/**DisplayPort** cable - depends on what connection does the monitor have that you are trying to connect. It's certainly possible.